# Can we access the 'Like' timestamp in Twitter?

Tags: twitter, tweepy, tweets, favorites, social-media-like

I am aware that using Twitter API endpoints, we can access the timestamp for a tweet or retweet. Can we access the timestamp when a user liked (or favorited) a tweet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not access the timestamp for a 'like'/'favorite' via the REST API, you can *see* 'like' actions via the [Streaming API User streams](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/userstreams), the problem is that you must be following the account that likes the Tweet before he performs the action to capture the event.

Events you can detect: https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/messages-types#Events_event

Comment: Thanks for the response Juan. With the REST API, I can get the count of likes but as you said we can't fetch the 'like' timestamps.